# "2+ Million" or "2 Million+"?

Tags: writing-style, abbreviations, numbers, symbols

When using a plus sign for brevity in a phrase like "over two million", where should the plus sign go?

- 2+ Million
- 2 Million+

The same concept would happen with thousand, billion, etc.

Comment: Bear in mind that is shorthand for the word plus but either way it's pretty colloquial. The plus comes at the end.

Comment: What would you say? Not "two plus million". _2+ million_ is ok for writing, but it's not English; in speech (and in ordinary writing) _two million plus_ is what English speakers would say. And don't worry about punctuations or hyphens -- they're not audible and apply only to writing, where nobody notices or cares.

Comment: If we were to parse it in a technical manner, it can be argued that 2+ million implies that the number of millions is unsure, whereas the + modifying the entire thing is just that the number itself is uncertain. There's a subtle difference in the meaning; the former seems less certain and with large deviation.

Comment: To reword that, "2+ million" suggests that it could be 2 million, 3 million, 4 million, etc. Whereas "2 million +" suggests something more like 2 million, 2.1 million, 2.2 million, etc.

Comment: Barmar's comment captures how the difference between the two expressions is likely to be understood, but using plus in this way is so informal, so intentionally casual, that it is probably misguided to expect a definite account of the correct way to so so. If one wants to convey some definite meaning without a possibility of misunderstanding, one should not use plus in this way at all.

Comment: I suggest Barmar would still be simply correct, even if 'intentionally casual' was a real thing.